# Emberjs: Accessing dynamic segment in nested routes/controllers

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have nested routes like this:

```
  this.resource('profile', { path: '/:user' }, function(){
    this.route('followers');
    this.route('following');
  });
```

I need an access to the value of 'user' dynamic segment in my followers/following routes/controllers.  One way I have figured out is to use

```
  this.controllerFor('profile').get('user')
```

inside my followers/following routes.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`route#modelFor`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor).

Example:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
        this.resource('comments');
    });
});

App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    afterModel: function() {
        this.set('post', this.modelFor('post'));
    }
});
```